# intent not started from Notification

Tags: android

I try to fire intent from notification:

```
CharSequence tickerText = "ServiceTicker"; // context.getString(R.string.service_ticker_registered_text);
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
nb.setTicker(tickerText);
nb.setWhen(when);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AccountRegistrationChanged.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

RegistrationNotification contentView = new RegistrationNotification(context.getPackageName());
contentView.clearRegistrations();
if(!Compatibility.isCompatible(9)) {
    contentView.setTextsColor(notificationPrimaryTextColor);
}
contentView.addAccountInfos(context, activeAccountsInfos);

nb.setOngoing(true);
nb.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
nb.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
nb.setContent(contentView);

Notification notification = nb.build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
// We have to re-write content view because getNotification setLatestEventInfo implicitly
notification.contentView = contentView;
Log.e(THIS_FILE, "==============notification:" + notification + " contentView:" + contentView + " notificationIntent:" + notificationIntent + " contentIntent" + contentIntent + " context:" + context + " nb:" + nb);

if (showNumbers) {
    // This only affects android 2.3 and lower
    notification.number = activeAccountsInfos.size();
}
startForegroundCompat(REGISTER_NOTIF_ID, notification);

private void startForegroundCompat(int id, Notification notification) {
    // If we have the new startForeground API, then use it.
    if (mStartForeground != null) {
        Log.e(THIS_FILE, "mStartForeground");

        mStartForegroundArgs[0] = Integer.valueOf(id);
        mStartForegroundArgs[1] = notification;
        invokeMethod(mStartForeground, mStartForegroundArgs);
        return;
    }
    Log.e(THIS_FILE, "invokeMethod");

    // Fall back on the old API.
    mSetForegroundArgs[0] = Boolean.TRUE;
    invokeMethod(mSetForeground, mSetForegroundArgs);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
}
```

and finally i have in logs, where is all intent and view created correctly:

10-04 22:38:49.344: E/Notifications(7415):

> ==============notification:Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0) contentView:com.csipsimple.widgets.RegistrationNotification@44eb3ff8
>   notificationIntent:Intent { flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.callsfreecalls.android/.AccountRegistrationChanged }
>   contentIntentPendingIntent{44eb3fe8: android.os.BinderProxy@44f08f98}
>   context:com.csipsimple.service.SipService@44e9c328
>   nb:android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder@44eb3e30 10-04
>   22:38:49.344: E/Notifications(7415): mStartForeground
>
> 10-04 22:38:49.344: E/Notifications(7415): mStartForeground

but nothing happened, this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(THIS_FILE, "AccountRegistrationChanged");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_registration_changed);
}
```

not started in Activity/AccountRegistrationChanged...

here is manifest for Activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".AccountRegistrationChanged"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_account_registration_changed" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Any suggestion? maybe i have to fire anything more to push notification start intent? 
Currently i just need activate some elements from another Activity, but code with handler (below is described) caused unknown error without any explanation in debug:

```
SipProfileState ps = activeAccountsInfos.get(i);
Message msg = new Message();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("regState",String.valueOf(ps.getStatusCode()));
msg.setData(b);
PhonePadActivity.getUareceiverhandler().sendMessage(msg);
```

Comment: @mah for all answered questions i was confirm and add point to correct answers. Maybe problem that i have a lot unanswered questions? i have now idea why.

Comment: I see what you're saying; I have deleted my prior comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the [`onNewIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) method of your `AccountRegistrationChanged` activity is being fired instead of `onCreate()`. Has the `AccountRegistrationChanged` activity already been created before your notification?

Comment: sorry for confirmation, but it not true. onCreate is never fired and onNewIntent too....

Comment: Is the `AccountRegistrationChanged` activity in your manifest?